# .htaccess redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hello I want to have some redirection made by .htaccess file:
Some examples

```
mysite.com/accepted -> mysite.com/index.php?type=accepted
mysite.com/waiting -> mysite.com/index.php?type=waiting
mysite.com/cancelled -> mysite.com/index.php?type=cancelled
```

&

```
mysite.com/edit/2 - > mysite.com/admin.php?edit=2
```

ETC. for all numbers possible

```
mysite.com/login -> mysite.com/admin.php?action=login
mysite.com/register -> mysite.com/admin.php?action=register
mysite.com/lostpassword - > mysite.com/admin.php?action=lostpassword 
mysite.com/add - > mysite.com/add.php
```

Apprectiate your help ;)

@edit: It should be done that way but with masking urls.

Comment: Are you sure you want this direction and not vice versa, rewriting requests of `/accept` internally to `/index.php?type=accept`?

Answer (score 1):

Which way around is the redirect?  It would be common to see redirects from your given right-hand-sides to the left-hand-sides, but not the other way around.

**EDIT** I see you've fixed that, so my supposition was correct:

i.e. you'd normally see:

```
RewriteRule ^edit/([0-9]+)$ /admin.php?edit=$1 [L]
```

etc, to map the nice friendly RESTful style URL into the internal URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get into the topic yourself, [www.modrewrite.com](http://www.modrewrite.com/) hosts a number of great mod_rewrite resources with lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your edit correctly you want this

```
<?php
header('Location: http://mysite.com/'.$_GET['type']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following?

```
RewriteRule ^www.domain.com/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [NC]
```

Do note that you will have to parse the URL (REQUEST_URI) instead of accessing `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no structural pattern in your URLs that can be used to map the URLs to the destinations, you probably will need to use one rule for each group like these:

```
RewriteRule ^add$ add.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(login|register|lostpassword)$ admin.php?action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/(\d+)$ admin.php?edit=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(accept|waiting|canceled)$ index.php?type=$1 [L]
```